# кодировка кириллицы ruby

Tags: ruby

Как решить проблему с кодировкой при парсинге страницы

```
#encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'
require 'active_support/all'


doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://ru.aliexpress.com/store/group/Phones/1986585_506350288.html?aff_platform=aaf&sk=eub6yrrBy%3A&cpt=1471512743432&af=10546_19&cv=89827&cn=2oc3mhzvpx218ax5wfqsxlopff9uebyo&dp=v5_2oc3mhzvpx218ax5wfqsxlopff9uebyo&afref=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2Faway.ph&aff_trace_key=12ce769729904d2e8018a43a518cc687-1471512743432-03970-eub6yrrBy'))
info = []
doc.css('.detail h3 a').map do |item|
  info.push(
    href: item['href'],
    title: item.inner_html
  )
end

puts info # выводит левые символы
```

думал трабл в консоли. пробовал гитовский шелл  - там то же самое + ко всему если просто puts "четотам" то кириллицу выводит

Comment: А вы в какой консоли запускаете? У меня выводит все по-русски. Возможно вы в Windows, консоль которой не поддерживает UTF-8?

Comment: ну сначало в виндовс консоли - там да не работает. Потом запустил гитбаш консоль там обычные выводы русского дают мне русский. Но когда парсится страница выдает бред на месте русского текста

Comment: Консоль bash/Mac OS X - все нормально, ваш скрипт выдает русский язык.

Comment: Для консоли используем команды "chcp  1251" (win кириллица) и "chcp 65001" (utf-8). Также замечено, что в RubyMine метод p вываливает юникод в кодах, а puts показывает нормально, а значит разница между этими методами есть. Это если вы в вин, а то не указано

Comment: chcp 1251 не помогает

Comment: chcp 1251 переключает консоль в Windows-1251, переключитесь в utf8, как советует vitidev

Comment: @cheops все относительно. В conemu (который у меня основной) chcp 65001 прекрасно работает, а в стандартном cmd выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 5):

Добрый день. Если я правильно понял проблема запуска срипта из ОС Windows.
Есть один хак, который я подсмотрел у преподавателя.
Нужно в начале скрипта вставить вот такой код:

```
if (Gem.win_platform?)
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
  Encoding.default_internal = __ENCODING__

  [STDIN, STDOUT].each do |io|
    io.set_encoding(Encoding.default_external, Encoding.default_internal)
  end
end
```

У себя попробовал как у Вас, такая же печаль, но с помощью данной модификации вывода STDOUT, становится все путем.

Comment: ох ты ж. наконец то рабочий хак. А то я раньше хаки разные пробовал и ни один не подошел. Уношу в заметки

Comment: вылазит ``inspect': inspected result must be ASCII only or use the default external encoding (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`